# how can i change property defined in object constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

if i have the below code , how can i change the isHTML property at any time while the application running ,i have tried the below and  tried many javascript access ways and it fails also.

```
obj = new ss({
    something: {
        ishtml: myfunction(true),
    },
});

document.getElementbyId("#id").onclick = function() {
    myfunction(false);
}

function myfunction(bool) {
    return bool;
}
```

after all of that when i use the application again it uses the intial values i send via the function

Comment: Maybe if you set the object to a variable like `test = { something: { ishtml: myfunction(true) } }`. You could use at any time `test.something.ishtml = myfunction(false);`

Comment: i can't , because ss is the parent of all of the plugin